# how order a mysql table from another table

Tags: mysql

I have two tables one is list of registered users the other contains timestamp for each user when ever they come online, so now i want to order the users table from the timestamp in the order table so i can tell if user is online or not but my code is not working, please i want did someone to help me out to fix my code i have being working since yesterday but can't still figure it out

```
SELECT * FROM table1.users WHERE id in
  (SELECT id FROM  table2.online_status ORDER BY timestamp)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just use a join?

```
SELECT * FROM table1 a
JOIN table2 b on
a.id = b.id
ORDER BY timestamp
```

Comment: but what of if i want to add condition to the first table by using where before joining with the other table how will i do that

Comment: just add it in a where clause after the join

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM table1.users t1
INNER JOIN table2.online_status t2 ON t2.id  = t1.id
ORDER BY t2.timestamp
```